# Codeigniter does NOT INSERT WHEN DELETE query EXISTS in the page

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I have problem in executing my insert query in CodeIgniter. If the delete query exist in the same class in my model, it somehow executes, making those that I have inserted to be deleted after execution.

The Process is to check if the SKLCDE is in the array of $skills, if not, it will be deleted in the database.

```
$this -> db -> select('SKLCDE');
$this -> db -> from('EmployeeSmartsDB');
$this -> db -> where('EMPNUM', $empnum);
$result = $this -> db -> get();

if ($result->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach ($result->result() as $row){
        if(!in_array($row->SKLCDE, $skills)){
            $this->db->where('EMPNUM', $empnum); 
            $this->db->where('SKLCDE', $row->SKLCDE); 
            $this->db->delete('EmployeeSmartsDB');
        }
    }
}
```

The insert query inserts the new SKLCDE in the database if it is not yet in the database.

Here's my code of my insert query:

```
$this -> db -> select('SKLCDE, RECSTS');
$this -> db -> from('EmployeeSmartsDB');
$this -> db -> where('EMPNUM', $empnum);
$this -> db -> where('SKLCDE', $skills[$i]);
$result2 = $this -> db -> get(); 
$data = array(
                       'YRSEM'  => '203101' ,
                       'EMPNUM' => '1234567' ,
                       'UNTCDE' => '1234' ,
                       'EMPCLS' => '1' ,
                       'EMPSTS' => '4' ,
                       'GRDLVL' => '0' ,
                       'SKLCDE' => '5S' ,
                       'QD1RTE' => '0' ,
                       'QD2RTE' => '0' ,
                       'QD3RTE' => '0' ,
                       'QD4RTE' => '0' ,
                       'RECSTS' => 'Y' ,
                       'SMTRTR' => '1234567',
                       'REMARK' => '' ,
                       'FTRNNG' => 'N'
                    );

$this->db->insert('EmployeeSmartsDB', $data);
```

**EDIT**

This is my code now, but still it is not working:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($skills); $i++){
$this -> db -> select('SKLCDE, RECSTS');
$this -> db -> from('EmployeeSmartsDB');
$this -> db -> where('EMPNUM', $empnum);
$this -> db -> where('SKLCDE', $skills[$i]);
$result2 = $this -> db -> get(); 
if($result2->num_rows() == 0){
$data = array(
                       'YRSEM'  => '203101' ,
                       'EMPNUM' => '1234567' ,
                       'UNTCDE' => '1234' ,
                       'EMPCLS' => '1' ,
                       'EMPSTS' => '4' ,
                       'GRDLVL' => '0' ,
                       'SKLCDE' => '5S' ,
                       'QD1RTE' => '0' ,
                       'QD2RTE' => '0' ,
                       'QD3RTE' => '0' ,
                       'QD4RTE' => '0' ,
                       'RECSTS' => 'Y' ,
                       'SMTRTR' => '1234567',
                       'REMARK' => '' ,
                       'FTRNNG' => 'N'
                    );

$this->db->insert('EmployeeSmartsDB', $data);
}
}
```

Comment: first you are checking if the SKLCDE is not in your array, then delete it. then you are creating a new array $data and inserting that in your table, but when are you checking if data exists or not while inserting ?

Comment: Just a simple question back: Why do you expect this should work?

Comment: @Deepanshu, Actually I have already a set of skills in the database. And when a skill in the database is not in the selected skills of the user, it must be deleted. And if a skill selected by the user is not in the database, it is inserted. So, it doesn't matter where the deleting part is placed. It is just THE SKILLS IN THE DATABASE including those not need to be deleted are being deleted after the insert... That's the problem. I am checking the database contents after the insert.

Comment: there is no if condition,.i.e,no checks if data already exists, when you are inserting, it is inserting the complete array

Comment: I've edited my code above, and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$this->db-> where(array('EMPNUM'=> $empnum, 'SKLCDE' => $skills[$i]))->insert('EmployeeSmartsDB', $data);
```

Comment: Hello guys, I think there really is a problem/BUG when executing two queries consecutively. For example, Update then Insert. I have solved my problem above by completely separating the two queries. I used Ajax to solve my problem. I execute the Ajax first then, continued on.